# html date and time pickers do not open in ios browsers when voiceover is on

Tags: html, ios, voiceover

I have `<input type="date">` on my page. Everything works fine, ie the date picker shows up when clicking the input. However, the date picker does not show up when voiceover is on.

I've tried several IPhones (tried safari and firefox) and they all behave the same way.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

One way it does work  is when user comes from another input of type text via "next control" button in VKB.

Is this a bug in iOS or what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We have the same bug in our app as well for iOS v13.x 
Replaced the native datepicker with numpad for this particular version